# How to delete records and related records dynamically from SObjects

Tags: apex, soql, schedulebatch

My Production org is almost full I need to delete Objects data and their related objects data based on SObjects mentioned in custom metadatatype.
I have written code to delete SObjects and related records but I am getting error

> FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: entity type AttachedContentDocument does not support query

Here is my code below for which I am getting that exception

```java
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult parentDescribe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(selectedObject).getDescribe();

List<Schema.ChildRelationship> childRelationships = parentDescribe.getChildRelationships();
List<AttachedContentDocument> attach = new List<AttachedContentDocument>();
List<Id>contentDocumentIdsToDelete = new List<Id>();
for (Schema.ChildRelationship childRelationship : childRelationships) {
    Schema.SObjectType childObjectType = childRelationship.getChildSObject();
    String relationshipFieldName = childRelationship.getField().getDescribe().getName();
    String child=childRelationship.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getName();
    Set<Id> parentRecordIds= new Set<Id>();
    for(SObject parentRecord:recordIds){
        
        parentRecordIds.add((Id)parentRecord.get('Id'));
        List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinks = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :parentRecord.Id];
        for (ContentDocumentLink contentDocumentLink : contentDocumentLinks) {
                contentDocumentIdsToDelete.add(contentDocumentLink.ContentDocumentId);
        }
    }

    if (!contentDocumentIdsToDelete.isEmpty()) {
            
        List<ContentDocument> contentDocumentsToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id IN :contentDocumentIdsToDelete];
        delete contentDocumentsToDelete;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`AttachedContentDocument`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_attachedcontentdocument.htm) is a read-only object read through a `describeSObject` call. If you delete the related `ContentDocumentLink`, you'll reduce the size of this object accordingly. Alternatively, if you delete `ContentDocument` records directly, you'll free up the associated file space usage. To prevent this error entirely, check the isQueryable property before attempting to perform a query:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult parentDescribe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(selectedObject).getDescribe();
if(!parentDescribe.isQueryable()) {
  // continue, next, break, or return, depending on how this code is written
}
// Rest of code...
```

Don't try to use `AttachedContentDocument` directly in Apex, as it isn't supported for querying.

Instead, you can query the files you need directly:

```
ContentDocumentLink[] links = Database.query(
  'SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink '+
  'WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (SELECT Id FROM '+
  selectedObject+')'
);
```

This query may fail for some large values of records (I don't have enough to test), so you may need to add a `LIMIT` clause and/or use actual API resources to get all the data you're looking for (e.g. Apex Data Loader or calling a describeSObjects API through REST or SOAP).